# Sending emails using React Emails

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nestjs

I using Next Js for front end, Nest Js for back end and AWS SES v2 for email service. Currently I am sending emails using EJS email templates that I made in back end. I would like to switch to React Emails. But React emails is generated at front end and use JSX, so how do I implement React Email in my project?

Comment: Are you confused how React Email uses React like syntax so it's only usable on the FrontEnd?

Answer (score 2):

## Installation & Basic Setup

React Email uses React for its syntax. You can use React Email in your backend like so:

1. Create something like an emails folder in your backend.
2. Install the required dependencies for it in your top level backend folder using `npm install react-email @react-email/button @react-email/html -E`
3. Add an `email:dev` script to your backend `package.json` like so:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "email dev"
  }
}
```

4. Create a demo email in your previously created `emails` folder like so:

```
import { Button } from "@react-email/button";
import { Html } from "@react-email/html";
import * as React from "react";

export default function Email() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Button
        href="https://example.com"
        style={{ background: "#000", color: "#fff", padding: "12px 20px" }}
      >
        Click me
      </Button>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

5. Preview using `npm run emails:dev`

---

## Sending emails

After all this, you have to actually send the emails. Follow these steps to get started sending them:

1. Create an API route called something like `/send-email`
2. In the API route, use the following code and adjust to your needs.

```js
import { render } from '@react-email/render';
import { SES } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
import Email from '../../emails/email';

const ses = new SES({ region: process.env.AWS_SES_REGION })

const emailHtml = render(Email({ url:"https://example.com" }));

const params = {
  Source: 'you@example.com',
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses: ['user@gmail.com'],
  },
  Message: {
    Body: {
      Html: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: emailHtml,
      },
    },
    Subject: {
      Charset: 'UTF-8',
      Data: 'hello world',
    },
  },
};

await ses.sendEmail(params);
```

---

Sources:

- Part one: [React email docs - Manual setup](https://react.email/docs/getting-started/manual-setup)
- Part two: [React email docs - AWS SES integration](https://react.email/docs/integrations/aws-ses)